# Where is the Volume "step size" in Blender 2.78?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I'm trying to adjust volume step size for accuracy in Blender, but cannot find the "Volume Sampling" section in the newest version, 2.78. For reference, here's what I'm referring to:

[image: Volume section Cycles Blender]

It seems to not be there for 2.78

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is now moved to the geometry panel:

Properties Window > Render Context > Geometry Panel > Step Size

[image]